Conditional Coloring Pandas Data frame
I am trying to conditionally add Color to Certain Cells(if change between current row's cell value and previous row cell value add red or green )in a Pandas Dataframe and export it to excel. But i am not getting the excel in colored format.
def get_change(current, previous):
    if current == previous:
        return 0
    try:
        return (abs(current - previous) / previous) * 100
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

def check_and_add():
    prev_row = 0
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if index == 0:
            prev_row = row
            continue
        value = get_change(row['AC0(BE)'], prev_row['AC0(BE)'])
        prev_row = row
        if(value > 10):
            return('background-color : red')
        else:
            return('background-color : green')

df = pd.DataFrame(listoflists)
df.rename(columns={0 : 'AC0(BE)',1: 'AC1(BK)',2: 'AC2(VI)',3: 'AC3(VO)'}, inplace=True)
df.style.apply(check_and_add,subset='AC0(BE)', axis = 1)
df.to_excel('styletest.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
#print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))


Any help would be appreciated
Expected result is colored cells

df.style.apply is not in place, you need to chain the to_excel call

Also, please provide a [mre], listoflists is undefined

@mozway listoflists is parseed from a text file so couldnt post it, but it goes like this listoflists = [[37,33,37,37],[47,33,47,47]]

One approach to achieving this is the following:
import pandas as pd

listoflists = [
    [100, 200, 300, 400],
    [105, 210, 310, 410],
    [95, 220, 320, 420],
    [110, 230, 330, 430],
]

def get_change(current, previous):
    if current == previous:
        return 0
    try:
        return (abs(current - previous) / previous) * 100
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

def check_and_add(df):
    prev_row = df.iloc[0]
    styles = pd.DataFrame('', index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        current_row = df.iloc[i]
        value = get_change(current_row['AC0(BE)'], prev_row['AC0(BE)'])
        if value > 10:
            styles.at[i, 'AC0(BE)'] = 'background-color: red'
        else:
            styles.at[i, 'AC0(BE)'] = 'background-color: green'
        prev_row = current_row
        
    return styles

df = pd.DataFrame(listoflists)
df.rename(columns={0: 'AC0(BE)', 1: 'AC1(BK)', 2: 'AC2(VI)', 3: 'AC3(VO)'}, inplace=True)

styled_df = df.style.apply(check_and_add, axis=None)
styled_df.to_excel('styletest.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)

which gives you

and in teh excel sheet


This works perfectly,i still donot understand how without going through row by row this style is added to cell and also how did you print it with color any sort of plugin i need to add in vscode to get this output?i am running in cmd line now

It's being taken care of by styles.at.
